# Adding business to Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-my-business

What is the best method of adding business on google map? which will show below the search result? will editing existing information make any changes to the search result?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Google Maps, you are provided with a link [put your business on Google Maps](http://www.google.com/local/add/g?hl=en-US&gl=US#phonelookup). If you follow the instructions, this should add you to the map.